# regex.test V.S. string.match to know if a string matches a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

Many times I'm using the string `match` function to know if a string matches a regular expression.

```html
if(str.match(/{regex}/))
```

Is there any difference between this:

```html
if (/{regex}/.test(str))
```

They seem to give the same result?

Comment: these are the best tests you will find http://jsperf.com/regexp-test-vs-match-m5

Comment: @ajax333221. Thanks for the jsperf, but I'm not sure it's a good one. The regex match using a match group, which isn't needed when looking a boolean value.

Comment: "Does a string match a presented pattern?" vs "Does my pattern match a presented string?". `str.match(/{regex}/)` seems more logical to read than `/{regex}/.test(str)`. Maybe next-gen javascript should include a `str.like(/{regex}/)` that behaves like test but reads like match.

Answer (score 575, accepted):

### Basic Usage

First, let's see what each function does:

*regexObject*.**[test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)**( *String* )

> Executes the search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns *true* or *false*.

*string*.**[match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**( *RegExp* )

> Used to retrieve the matches when matching a string against a regular expression. Returns an array with the matches or `null` if there are none.

Since `null` evaluates to `false`,

```
if ( string.match(regex) ) {
  // There was a match.
} else {
  // No match.
}
```

---

### Performance

Is there any difference regarding performance?

**Yes**. I found this short note in the [MDN site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> If you need to know if a string matches a regular expression regexp, use regexp.test(string).

Is the difference significant?

The answer once more is **YES**! This [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/test-vs-match-regex) I put together shows the difference is  **~30% - ~60%** depending on the browser:

[image: test vs match | Performance Test]

### Conclusion

Use `.test` if you want a faster boolean check. Use `.match` to retrieve all matches when using the `g` global flag.

Comment: Not too surprised since the string function needs to flip things around and then create the Array if there's a match. Looks like I'll keep using `.test()`. :)

Comment: what about a perf for actually extracting the value....also why not throw a 3rd case in for .exec().

Comment: @livingston_mechanical, because it wasn't the subject of the post.

Comment: My two cents: performance is overrated. Either option can do ~15,000 operations in the flicker of a monitor, so unless you're doing bulk regex client-side, speed isn't relevant. Of course 'test' is logically the correct function if a boolean result is what you're after. Thanks for the Q/A BTW.

Comment: What about test() vs. indexOf()

Comment: Interestingly test is 41% slower than match for me using the jsPerf test above (Chrome 41, OSX).

Comment: @Benjie Similar result: test is 21% slower than match for me on Chromium 42, OSX (±3% over 4 runs).

Comment: @AlexShilman indexOf is faster (but not much) than test according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/183496/javascript-style-optimization-string-indexof-v-regex-test (you'd expect it to be faster).

Comment: .match() didn't work for me for some reason, with the same regex that i used in .test(), maybe a typo, no idea.

Comment: another performance considerations about searching in strings: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296268/fastest-way-to-check-a-string-contain-another-substring-in-javascript

Comment: One thing that might bite you here (it bit my team recently): If you use the 'g' flag on your Regex and create a new instance (i.e. via new RegExp(<regex_str>, 'g')) and you reuse that instance, running "test" is stateful, i.e. will return different results when run multiple times. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Using_test()_on_a_regex_with_the_global_flag for details.

Comment: @DavidGilbertson - Your remark was worth much more than two cents to me. I was wondering about the practical impact of the performance issue. Thanx for clearing that up!

Answer (score 197):

Don't forget to take into consideration the global flag in your regexp :

```
var reg = /abc/g;
!!'abcdefghi'.match(reg); // => true
!!'abcdefghi'.match(reg); // => true
reg.test('abcdefghi');    // => true
reg.test('abcdefghi');    // => false <=
```

This is because Regexp keeps track of the lastIndex when a new match is found.

Comment: I was just head banging seeing that my regex.test() was randomly logging "true" then "false" then "true"...thanks!

Comment: I think this is the better answer. It explains that they don't give the same result and that reg.test() has a dangerous pitfall. To me this makes string.match() the clear choice. Performance has never been any issue for me.

Comment: This is important!  Going crazy trying to figure out why every other result was missing...for reference of anyone else that finds this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex

Comment: If you're as confused as I was, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1520800/3714913. There's also [String.prototype.search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search), which returns an index but doesn't have this issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: Just curious, what's the point of having a global flag for `.test()`? isn't the point of `.test()` to check if the string has a matching regexp?

Comment: regexp.test(...) should never really have the global flag set on the regexp unless you are looking through a bunch of text wanting to count matches.

Comment: @buhbang when you have a regex and use for multiple purposes. In here you test() a string, in there you split/replace a string or do something else.