# Performance - match() vs. exec() for extracting a single value

Tags: javascript

Suppose I need a single value from a string, say a version number.  Should I use exec() or match()?

**Snippet1**

```
res1 = /(\d+\.\d+)/.exec(some_string)[0];
```

vs

**Snippet2**

```
res1 = some_string.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
```

which is better?

Comment: Duplicate I'm afraid, but it's got an excellent answer!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression

Comment: Don't use `RegExp.$0`, but the [`exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) method: `/(\d+\.\d+)/.exec(some_string)[0];` (you should validate if `.exec` returns a non-`null` value, otherwise an error is raised (same applies to `.match`).

Comment: @livingston_mechanical There's a crucial difference:  `.exec` is a method of a `RegExp` instance, whereas `.match` is only defined for strings. Using `some_string.match` would throw an error if `some_string` is not a string.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical You've updated your question to something different. What answer are you expecting? There's no difference except for what I mentioned in my previous comment (unless the global modifier (`/g`) is used in the regular expression, which is not the case).

Comment: @Chris Cooney - http://jsperf.com/match-vs-exec-1 .... match is faster in this case!

Comment: You have "test" in your first line instead of "exec"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd use `match` because it can be kept on one line, but it's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 3):

You can measure the performance of your code using https://jsbench.me/.