# Find specific digit in a number using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable with a certain value, let's say for example `var no = 123056`.
Is there a way to determine if that number contains the digit 0, with the help of `RegExp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
var no = 12045;
var patt1=/0/; // search pattern

if (no.toString().match(patt1) !== null){
    // contains the character 0
    alert("character '0' found")
} else {
    // does not contain 0
    alert("'0' not found")
};
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frxmu/) for it.

Comment: `g` is a performance penalty here as he's asking only if one exist. and `i`-case insensitive for numbers isn't doing anything.

Comment: What about the second issue? and you should read  [`test` vs `match`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10940137/601179).

Comment: Still early in the morning for me, obviously need more coffee. Also very good information in the link.

Comment: Thanks, it's my Q&A there... I'll keep the comments here as they have value.

Answer (score 3):

```
var no = 123056
var doesZeroExist = (no+"").indexOf('0') > -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use RegExp, yes, it is possible:

`/0/` to match a 0. Replace 0 with any other number, including 10+

`/[035]/` to match one of 0, 3 OR 5. Replace them with any number you want.

If you want a sequence of a number, add a `+` after it.

`/(012)+/` will match 1 to infinite consecutive groups of 012, like 012, 012012, 012012012 ...

`/012+/` will match 01 and 1 to infinite number of 2, like, 012, 0122, 01222 ...

Also, the best RegExp tool you will probably want to use: http://www.debuggex.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
var no='123056';
var regex=/0/;
if (no.match(regex) == 0) {
   alert('hey');
}
```

This will give you an alert message if the 0 is found.

Comment: `== 0`? what would it be 0?