# TypeError: pattern.test is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I'm writing a register form which has a ton of javascript included. While writing the basic functions to check the format of certain strings, I came across this problem (I've tried to solve it by myself but no luck there). In this simplified version I have three functions: one to check the format of phone number, second to check the format of email and third to combine those two functions to make it more clear. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script>
        function filterPhone(phone){
            var pattern = "/^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/";
            return pattern.test(phone);
        }

        function filterEmail(email) {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
            return regex.test(email);
        }

        function checkForm(){
            var puh = document.getElementById("puh").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            if(filterPhone(puh) && filterEmail(email)){
                alert("It works");
                return true;
            } else {
                alert("Check the format!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="" name="regForm" onsubmit="return checkForm()">
    <input type="text" name="puh" id="puh" placeholder="Phonenumber"><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Check!">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I only use the function filterEmail it works fine but when I use them both (or even only the filterPhone!) it gives me an error: **"TypeError: pattern.test is not a function"** ("pattern" referring to the first function's (filterPhone) variable name called pattern). I've tried using exec() instead of test() and changing the regex-pattern, neither have worked. This is rather weird since the syntax seems to be correct. Why could be the reason?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Your `pattern` must be RegEx literal (double quotes around that should not be there) like this

```
var pattern = /^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/;
```

Otherwise you need to use [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object, with proper escaping for `\`, like this

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^(()?\\d{3}())?(-|\\s)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4}$");
```

Comment: RegEx literal (double quotes around that should not be there), that's something new for me. Thanks.

Comment: In my case I changed `value.test(/*/)` to `value.match(/*/)` and it worked, here's the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 18):

Your pattern holds a **string**, and not a regular expression.

Make it `var pattern = /^(()?\d{3}())?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)?\d{4}$/;` (without quotes)

Answer (score 4):

Encountered a similar issue.

**Solution**: use `.match()` instead of `.test()` method

Answer (score 4):

Also, make sure to write `/pattern/.test("string")` as opposed to `"string".test(/pattern/)`.