# Javascript regular expression match string to start with letter or number

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I am trying to see if my string starts with a letter or a number. I think I'm close, could anyone help me out?

```
if(thestring.match("/^[\pL\pN]/"))
```

Comment: specifically which letters or numbers?

Comment: 0-9, a-z, A-Z @user3334690

Comment: If you want to check for 0-9, a-z, A-Z then why don't you use `/^[0-9a-zA-Z]/`?

Comment: Why you are testing against Unicode characters?

Comment: Thank you @Juana, my problem was mainly the quotes in that `match()`. That's why I went to the unicode because I thought I was doing something wrong with the regex.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
^[A-Z0-9]
```

With a case-insensitive modifier:

```
if(thestring.match(/^[A-Z0-9]/i)) {}
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/vU8eV7)

---

`\pL` and `\pN` are PCRE shortcodes and do not work in Javascript.

Comment: Hmm the demo work's great, but the javascript doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

```
if(/^[a-z0-9]/i.test(thestring)) {
    //do something
}
```

`.test()` is much more simple.
It returns just `false` or `true`, while `.match()` resturns `null` or an array.

[More information differences between .test() and .match()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression)