# username validation using javascript by document.getElementbyid()

Tags: javascript

```
<form method="POST" name="myform" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="return validate();">Firstname
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname">
    <br/>
    <br/>
</form>
```

My JavaScript validation is

```
function validate() {

    var A = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    if (A !== /^[a-zA-Z]/) {
        alert("enter letters only");
        return false;
    }
```

I want only alphabet letters to enter and if numbers entered means the alert will be displayed.Can any one help me

Comment: You cannot just compare the regex with string, use regex functions.  Change `if (A !== /^[a-zA-Z]/) {` ==> `if( !(/^[a-z]+$/i.test(A)))`

Comment: You may also want to use jQuery validation plugin instead of reinventing the wheel and writing your own validator.

Comment: I'd also recommend to use `pattern` attribute. `<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to properly check, if the Regex matches the string:

```
function validate () {

   var A = document.getElementById("firstname").value;
   if(!(/^[a-z]+$/i.test(A)))
   {
      alert ("enter letters only");
      return false;
   }
}
```

Additionally the regexp neded to make sure that there is at least one character entered (that is done by the + modificator) and that the a-zA-Z rule applies from start (^) to end ($)

Comment: Better to use `test` instead of `match`, `test` is used to check if string follows some pattern, `match` is used to extract a pattern from string.

Comment: I agree. Good point: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression