# Getting only the match, instead of whole entry

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

With help of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469419/regex-and-array-most-efficient-approach/35469509) I got the following piece of code, which find all occurrences of words with at least 3 letters:

```
arr = ["ab", "abcdef", "ab test"]

var AcceptedItems = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.match(/[a-zA-Z]{3,}/);
});
```

In my case that should be `abcdef` and `test`.

But instead of the occurrences only, it gets me the whole entry of the array. So instead of just `test` it gets me `ab test`.

How can I get only the match (`test`), not the whole array entry.

Comment: `arr.map(item.match....[0]).filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.filter` will keep an element if it matches the predicate you passed but you need to save a new value based on if that predicate is true. You could do this by first performing a `map` then a `filter` but I'd rather do this in one loop.

```
var AcceptedItems = [];
for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
  var match = arr[i].match(/[a-zA-Z]{3,}/);
  if (match) {
    AcceptedItems.push(match[0]);
  }
}
```