# I cant validate the 2nd condition

Tags: jquery

This is my html button code

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" />
    <div class="help-block with-errors" style="font-size:12pt">Input Only Alphabet</div>
</div>
 <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" id="button1 style="height:50px; width:100px" />
```

This is my jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#button1").click(function(){
        if($("#name").val() == null)
            alert("haha");

        if($("#name").val() == [a-z])
            alert("zzzz");
    });
</script>
```

My problem is i only can validate the first condition. Everytime i try 2nd condition it wont work. Anyone can help see what is my problem??

Comment: your quoting in the string has munged up, look at the id and style!

Answer (score 3):

This is invalid syntax<sup>*</sup>:

```
if($("#name").val() == [a-z])
```

You could do what you want with a regular expression:

```
if($("#name").val().test(/^[a-z]$/))
```

The additional `^` and `$` require the element's value to be just that one character, with nothing before nor after it.

Secondly, your `input` does not have an `id` attribute, so jQuery will not find anything with `$("#name")`. For that to work your input element must have `id="name"`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name"/>
                                                    ^^
```

---

<sup>*</sup> technically, it is in fact correct syntax, but for something entirely different: it would look up variables *a* and *z*, subtract them, and use the result for a single-element array literal, which would not give the expected result.

Comment: [*Use `.test()`*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138/645186). Also, probably that character set should have the starting `^` and ending position `$` specifiers. So, the check would actually make more sense with the equality.

Comment: i tried but i still keep show me HAHA no matter what i type

Comment: @Ron, could you add to your question the HTML of the `name` element? Does it have the `id='name'` attribute?

Comment: It does not have the `id` attribute. You need that. When you reference `$('#name')`, jQuery does not find your input, unless it has that `id` (not `name`). Could you please also fix the error in the other HTML? There is a closing double quote missing after `button1`.

Comment: @Ron, did this solve your issue? Could you give some feed-back?