# Javascript - Is test() and match() in javascript same?

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between test() and match()?

I know both are used for searching a match in a string.
My question is can we use both interchangeably in our code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no.These are different

Comment: _can we use both interchangeably in our code?_ **Yes** since `null` and `false` are both falsy value. **NO** if you're comparing result with `false` or `null`. Check if pattern exists in a string use `test()`. Get the string matched by pattern, use `match()`.

Comment: test() returns a boolean, match() returns null or an array. if you don't need the matching results, test() is faster.

Comment: can you please explain when we are using these(like real case scenerios)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. `.test()` is for **RegExp** while `.match` is intended for **strings**

**.match()**

> The match() method retrieves the matches when matching a string against a regular expression.
>   **Syntax**: `str.match(regexp)`

**.test()**

> The test() method executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns true or false.
>   **Syntax**: `regexObj.test(str)`

For a more detailed explanation on this, refer this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138/3878940

MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Answer (score 1):

.test()  -  returns a Boolean whether there is a match or not. It never returns what actually matches.
.match() - is a method on a string and returns one set of results.

Answer (score 0):

This questions already discussed. Please refer this below link. I hope it will help you.

[regex.test V.S. string.match to know if a string matches a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression)

Thank you!