# Check if string starts with a number

Tags: javascript

How would I do something like this in javascript:

```
var s = '124sdg';
var f = 'hsdsda';
if (s.startsWith(a number)) {
   // Return true
}
if (f.startsWith(a number)) {
   // Return false
}
```

Answer (score 39):

You can use a regular expression:

```
if (s.match(/^\d/)) {
   // Return true
}
if (f.match(/^\d/)) {
   // Return false
}
```

Comment: This answer is overrated. If we only need to check the regex against the value, `.test` performs better. Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138/2832556).

Comment: Yes, agreed, `test` is better here.

Answer (score 26):

use a regex...

```
/^\d/.test(s)
```

which will return true or false if the first digit is a number or not