# Validate number formats in a contact form (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a function to validate phone number in a contact form, but i need to be able to put in "xxx xxx xxxx" for example, and not just "xxxxxxxx"

The number format should be:

xxx xxx xxxx

xxx-xxx-xxxx

xxx.xxx.xxxx

```
  function validatePhone() {
    var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;

    if (phone.length == 0) {
      var w = document.getElementById("phoneError").textContent;
      alert(w);
      return false;
    }

    if (phone.length != 10) {
      var r = document.getElementById("phoneError").textContent;
      alert(r);
      return false;
    }

    // THIS IS NOT WORKING
    if (
      !phone.match(/^[0-9]{10}$/) ||
      !phone.match(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/) ||
      !phone.match(/^\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}$/)
    ) {
      var t = document.getElementById("phoneError").textContent;
      alert(t);
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: consider an input mask...will be it easier on you and the user...there are a ton of them out there for jquery...easy to use

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "This is not working" part, which cases are failing?

Comment: A dash cannot be a dot. I imagine you intended to use `&&`. Also `RegExp.prototype.test` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen  I tested the others above, and they worked, so just added that comment yesterday for myself to remember, its part of a longer code (its a school assignment!) ^^,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: First, you are mixing up AND and OR:

```
if (
  !phone.match(/^[0-9]{10}$/) ||
  !phone.match(/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/) ||
  !phone.match(/^\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}$/)
) {
```

As soon as one of the conditions fails, it will return false (which is basically always). You want this `if` to apply, when none of the expressions matches, e.g. when all of them are `false`. Therefor, you have to use `&&` instead of `||`. Not a AND not b AND not c.

Second: your 3rd regex is a bit off: `.` means "any character", so this regex would also match "123x123y1234". You need to escape the dot with a backslash: `/^\d{3}\.\d{3}\.\d{4}$/`

Also, you can improve this code significantly. You have 5 conditions, which could all be handled in one (if you want to allow the input of "123.123 234", otherwise you will have to do it using 3 regex). And for just checking if a regex matches a string, you maybe should use `test()`, [because it is just slightly faster](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138/7933618) (it won't matter in your case, but just out of principle).

You can reduce your code to:

```
if (/^\d{3}[\s-.]\d{3}[\s-.]\d{4}$/.test(document.getElementById("phone").value) === false) {
    alert (document.getElementById("phoneError").textContent);
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a good answer! :-D This helps a lot!