# Adding Regex to a Vue.js Data Object

Tags: javascript, regex, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to manipulate a URL so that it removes everything after the last `/` and then I append my own filename to the end.

The regex to remove everything after the final `/` is `[^\/]+$` .

I tried the code from the URL below but the mounted function doesn't seem to work. Not sure if that is because of Vue2 or not, as the post is 18 months old.

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/binding-a-regexp-object-to-an-html-attribute/815

```
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: '#vue-instance',
        data: {
            myimage: ''
        }
        });
        
    /* Regex to add is [^\/]+$ */
```

Here is the code in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nyuxka9/) .

How can I incorporate the regex to convert the url to output in the HTML?

Comment: computed property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Regex pattern

The regex pattern you mention would match the last path segment of the URL (i.e., the text *after* the last slash) ([demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/4M4Mh7/1)), but the code comment indicates you want it to match everything **before** the last slash, which would instead require a pattern like the following ([demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/nuTlgZ/1)):

```
^(.+)\/.*$
```

*Explanation of regex pattern broken down:*

```
^    # assert position at start of line
(    # Start group 1
.+   # match any character (except line terminators), one or more times
)    # End group 1
\/   # match `/` literally
.*   # match any character (except line terminators), zero or more times
$    # assert position at end of line
```

Notice [capture group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references) #1 contains the URL parts you want, and you could extract it as follows:

```js
const url = 'https://google.com/foo/bar';
const regex = /^(.+)\/.*$/ig;
const matches = regex.exec(url);
console.log(matches[1]) /* 1 = group index */
```

### Computed property

You could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) that would contain a valid [`URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) based on the string in `this.myimage`. In the following example, the `imgUrl` computed property parses `this.myimage` to ensure it's a valid `URL`, and uses a regular expression to parse the text before the last slash, which it then prefixes to `/home.jpg`:

```
computed: {
  imgUrl() {
    let url = this.myimage;

    // validate URL in `this.myimage`
    try {
      url = new URL(url).toString();
    } catch (e) {
      url = '';
    }

    if (url) {
      const regex = /^(.+)\/.*$/ig;
      const matches = regex.exec(url);
      return matches && `${matches[1]}/home.jpg`;
    }
  }
}
```

Note the computed property returns `undefined` if `this.myimage` is an invalid URL. This means `this.imgUrl` would be `undefined` if the text input contained `xyz`, but it would be `http://google.com/a/b` if the input had `http://google.com/a/b/c`. With that in mind, we replace the `v-show` variable with `imgUrl` so that the `<img>` is only shown when `imgUrl` is defined and not empty (i.e., when `this.myimage` is a valid URL string). We also replace the value of `v-bind:src` with `imgUrl`, since it will already contain the full intended URL with `/home.jpg` appended:

```
<img v-show="imgUrl" v-bind:src="imgUrl">
```

[updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld/jbh3pack/)

Comment: I am reading that regex.text is a better approach.  having issues using this option but checkout this one first   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression

Comment: @AtLeastTheresToast `regex.test` doesn't provide the matches, which is needed in this case.