# Why .test() and .match() have opposite syntax? What's the reason behind that?

Tags: javascript

I just learned about those methods and tried to google it, but found nothing

```
'string'.match(/regex/);
/regex/.test('string');
```

Why do they take `/regex/` and `'string'` vice versa?

Comment: I'd like to ask you the opposite. Is there any valid reason for not allowing regexp to be used with string or string to be used with regexp? What's the justification for removing one of the two methods?

Comment: "Why do they take /regex/ and 'string' vice versa?" Matching string over regexp requires you to have both. Having one as a context kinda implies you need the other as an argument.  How would you suggest those methods to be implemented differently?

Comment: as i understood that means that  it works that way : ```context.method(argument)```    and the context return a response?

Answer (score 3):

(Reposting my comment as an answer)

Because a `String` isn't a `RegExp` and vice-versa.

If the JavaScript standard library did use the same function name in both cases then it would cause confusion because the two methods return **very different** values.

JavaScript does not implement static-typing so without using the different names `match` and `test` someone reading the code wouldn't know if the return value type is `string[] | null` or `bool` (remember also that JavaScript doesn't allow true function overloading).

See [regex.test V.S. string.match to know if a string matches a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression)

- `String.match` returns `string[] | null`.
- `RegExp.test` returns `bool`.

So if you see this code...:

```
function doSomething( foo, bar ) {

    return foo.match( bar );
}
```

...then (assuming `foo` is a `string`) then you *know* that `doSomething` will return a `string[] | null` value.

And if you see this...:

```
function doSomething( foo, bar ) {

    return foo.test( bar );
}
```

...Then (assuming `foo` is a `RegExp`) then you *know* that `doSomething` will return a `bool` value.