# Only highlight elements without parents in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to highlight any element that has English characters. The code is highlighting the parent elements also. How can I stop this?

Actually, the regular explession is not important. I just need to highlight the single element in any condition. Please only JavaScript not JQuery. Thank you.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>日本</h1>
<div>
    <div>日本</div>
    <div>1234</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>abcd</div>
    <div>日本</div>
</div>

<script>
    document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach((ele) => {
        let chars = /[a-zA-Z]/;
        if(ele.textContent.match(chars)) {
            ele.style.border = "3px solid red";
        }
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `textContent` of the parent divs contains all the text of its children

Comment: A parent element contains also its child elements and their text content. Split the text into textnodes containing latin characters, and highlight the parent nodes of the the newly-created textnodes.

Answer (score 1):

`querySelectorAll('*')` will select all elements in the document. The nicest solution would be to pass a selector string that matches only the elements you might want to match - such as `div > div`, divs which are an immediate child of another div.

`.test` would also be a [tiny bit better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10940138) (semantically and performance-wise) than `.match`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div > div').forEach((ele) => {
  if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(ele.textContent)) {
    ele.style.border = "3px solid red";
  }
});
```

```html
<h1>日本</h1>
<div>
  <div>日本</div>
  <div>1234</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>abcd</div>
  <div>日本</div>
</div>
```

An approach that would be more general, but more prone to breaking things simply because it's so general, would be to select [all text nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579666/getelementsbytagname-equivalent-for-textnodes) (**not elements**), and if the node text contains what you're looking for, change the style of their parent element.

```js
function nativeTreeWalker() {
    var walker = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.body,
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT, 
        null, 
        false
    );

    var node;
    var textNodes = [];

    while(node = walker.nextNode()) {
        textNodes.push(node);
    }
    return textNodes;
}

for (const textNode of nativeTreeWalker()) {
  if (/[a-zA-Z]/.test(textNode.textContent)) {
    textNode.parentElement.style.border = "3px solid red";
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>日本</h1>
<div>
  <div>日本</div>
  <div>1234</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>abcd</div>
  <div>日本</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `test` is probably better than `match` here

Comment: Thank you so much! Both answers are great, but I should have mentioned that the tag name could be anything and not just divs. However, I really like your nativeTreeWalker solution. That's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer suggests, you may want to pay attention to text nodes.

Here is example code:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function (el) {
    const cn = el.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < cn.length; i++) {-
        if (cn[i].nodeName === '#text' && cn[i].data.match(chars)) {
             // This el contains text we care about in a text node.
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly too and easy to understand. I kind of feel stupid now that you got this so quickly. Regards

Comment: @tony That feeling means you are learning  I have lots of experience, so don’t imagine it means I am smarter or anything. In fact, I based my answer on a snippet of code I recently rewrote to remove jQuery usage; it’s live on alanhogan.com and it helps avoid typographical 'orphans' in headlines.

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet will do the job:

```js
function hilite(el,rx){
  let n, walk=document.createTreeWalker(el,NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,{ acceptNode: n=>rx.test(n.textContent)});
  while(n=walk.nextNode()) n.parentElement.classList.add("bold")
}
hilite(document,/[a-zA-Z]/);
```

```css
.bold {font-weight:900; color:red}
```

```html
<h1>日本</h1>
<div>
  <div>日本</div>
  <div>1234</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div>abcd</div>
  <div>日本<span> and this span too!</span></div>
</div>
```

The iterable object `walk` created with `document.createTreeWalker()` will find all text-nodes matching the specified regular expression `rx` and will add the class `bold` to each of their `.parentElement`s.