# How to check valid regex on select

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-kapitsa-c00jdz)

```
    const SelectSizesDemo = () => {
      const pattern = new RegExp(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i);
      const errorMsg = "please provide valid email!";

      const [emailArr, setEmailArr] = useState([]);
      const [error, setError] = useState(false);

      return (
        <div>
          <Select
            style={{ width: "90%" }}
            mode="tags"
            onChange={(e) => setEmailArr(e)}
          ></Select>
          {error && errorMsg}
        </div>
      );
    };
```

I am trying to do the following. The user should input some email, if its email is valid with my `pattern` then I should add it to my `emailArr`, if it's not correct then I should show the error message `errorMsg`, clear from the selected items and not allow the user to add it to the array.

In this code, I successfully can add any string to my array, so I want your help to understand how can I check that string with my `pattern`.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: updated [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rrbkw1?file=index.js) but not working correctly

Comment: So do you actually have a "problem" or are you just unsure of how to implement this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've worked on [your updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rrbkw1?file=index.js) and figured out what was the problem.

**[Here is my full code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rrbkw1-3h7bwu?file=index.js) before I start explaining to you what I changed.**

### **Explanations:**

- So first, in order to make the `select` always have the values of the `emailArr`, you need to **bind** it to that state with the
  **`value`** attribute. **This way, any change in the `emailArr` state will be applied to the `select` values too.**

  So simply you add:  `value = {emailArr}`  in the `select`.
- Second, in the `onChange` event you get an **array** in the `e`
  object which is the array of the current values that are in the select
  field. So in order to test the value, you need to check the
  validation of the **current** value that was inserted to that array, which is the
  **last** one in it.

  In your code you check the validation of the entire array which cause
  it to not work correctly:

  **Your code:**

  ```
    onChange={(e) => {
        if (pattern.test(e)) {
          setEmailArr(e);
        } else {
          setError(true);
        }
      }}
  ```

  **Should be:**

  ```
   onChange={(e) => {
        if (e.length !== 0) {//First check if the array is not empty 

          const value = e[e.length - 1]; //get the last(current) value from the array
          if (pattern.test(value)) {
            setEmailArr(e);
            setError(false);
          } else {
            setError(true);
          }

        }
      }}
  ```

  So Here, I first check if the `e` array is not empty. Because if I
  check the last value of **an empty array** it will be `undefined` - which is
  `false`, and this will go to the `else` block and set the error to
  true, which is wrong. So that's why I start these checks only if
  there's something to check in the array.

  Next, I check the current value, if it's valid you update the state
  **(which need to be combined with the `select`)** to the new array with the new value, otherwise - it won't.  And by the way, I added `setError(false)` in
  case that there was an invalid try before and I want to hide the
  previous error now.

**And a note**: The emails you enter in the select must be **capitalized** in order to match the pattern you chose. If you don't want it then just change it to this pattern: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/g`.

**Result**:

[image: ACTION.gif]

So that's it. I hope everything was clear, and please check [the full code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rrbkw1-3h7bwu?file=index.js).

Comment: btw I just changed regex only `/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i`

Answer (score 1):

You can validate string with regex using this code :

```js
onChange={(e) => {
              if(pattern.test(e.target.value)){
              setEmailArr(e.target.value)
              }else{
                setError(true)
              }
 }}
```

Comment: Agree with this solution, but the problem is another thing, for example, if it's incorrect it's not adding to the array but it's added to my selected items. https://ibb.co/HGCWdR8

Comment: You have to override default events of the `antd` Select component that you are using . try overriding `onBlur`

Comment: I tried it's not working your suggested way .... here is your [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-g2gszj?file=index.js)... it's adding one time into my array, and for other times it is not added.

Answer (score 1):

The goal of this solution is to tell antd to use "our" email list instead of using "their" internal list.

`onChange` is called when a new element is added to the list. Check the last element and see if it's valid and then update your internal email list with antd's email list.

I use [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which automatically handles duplicates, but you could do this with only lists if you prefer.

Whenever the emailSet changes I update the email list alphabetically, but you don't need to do this if you don't want. A simple `[...emailSet]` is sufficient.

`onDeselect` seems to be called when the last element is removed, so I just clear the rest of the elements.

```js
const SelectSizesDemo = () => {
  const pattern = new RegExp(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i);

  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [emailSet, setEmailSet] = useState(new Set());
  const emails = useMemo(() => {
    return [...emailSet].sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b));
  }, [emailSet]);

  const addEmail = (e) => {
    if(e.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const email = e[e.length - 1];
    if (!pattern.test(email)) {
      setError(errorMsg);
      return;
    }
    setEmailSet(new Set(e))
    if (error) {
      setError(false);
    }
  };

  const clearAll = () => {
    setEmailSet(new Set([]));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Select
        style={{ width: "90%" }}
        mode="tags"
        onChange={addEmail}
        onDeselect={clearAll}
        value={emails}
      ></Select>
      {error && errorMsg}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Full solution [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-oskar-1j3m65?file=/index.js).

Comment: I think `Set` is unnecessary because antd `<Select />` component removes duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, You want to test the email based on the input value enter by the user and if its a valid email as per the pattern you want to store that in an array else you want to show the error message. If Yes, Here you go **:**

To validate an email, You can use the RegEx [`test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) method which executes a search for a match between a regular expression and a specified string. Returns `true` if the email is valid else returns `false`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const {useState, useCallback} = React;

function Example() {
    const [emailArr, setEmailArr] = useState([]);
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);
    
    function isValidEmail(email) {
      const pattern = new RegExp(/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i);
      return pattern.test(email);
    }
    
    const handleEmailValidation = event => {
      const errorMsg = "please provide valid email!";

      if (!isValidEmail(event.target.value)) {
        setError(errorMsg);
      } else {
        setEmailArr(oldArray => [...oldArray, event.target.value]);
        setError(null);
      }
    };
    
    return (
        <div>
          <input
            id="email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleEmailValidation}
          />
          {error && <span class="error">{error}</span>}
          
          <div>{emailArr.map(entry =>
            <div>{entry}</div>
          )}
          </div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Moein, `pattern.test(string)` is a valid way of checking if the user's input string matches your regex pattern.

Alternatively, you can use `String.match(regex)` to get an array of matches or null. This can still be used to evaluate truthiness.

Comparison was discussed here: [regex.test V.S. string.match to know if a string matches a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to use regex method as pattern.test(yourString)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).