# Differences between new RegExp(pattern) and pattern.test(string)

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to create a strong password rule for JavaScript with regex. However, i find a strange result using different approach.

First approach (worked):

```
const value = 'TTest90()';
const firstApproach = /^(?=(.*[a-z]){3,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[0-9]){2,})(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_+?.]){2,}).{8,}$/.test(value);
```

The variable `firstApproach` is true witch is intended result.

The next approach is using the new RegExp like:

```
const pattern = '/^(?=(.*[a-z]){3,})(?=(.*[A-Z]){2,})(?=(.*[0-9]){2,})(?=(.*[!@#$%^&*()\-_+?.]){2,}).{8,}$/';
const regex = new RegExp(pattern);
const secondApproach = regex.test(value);
```

But, `secondApprocach` now is false with the same regex.

I can't find why secondApproach variable isn't true because is the same regex.

I am asking this question because I want to understand where I am going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: you may find your answer to here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10940137/regex-test-v-s-string-match-to-know-if-a-string-matches-a-regular-expression

Comment: That's right, thank you. Sorry for the duplicate post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put the "/" inside the string in your pattern.

More specifically, the `/..../` is a specific javascript syntax to create a RegExp.

So `/something/` is like writing `new RegExp('something')`. You are instead writing `new RegExp('/something/')`

Comment: So this is a typo?